# How can I create a form dynamically and submit it in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I need to first call a API get some values put in my form then submit it. I like to avoid having a form with hidden inputs and want to create it on the fly. My pseudo code

```
submitMyform() {
  //first i call an API and get some data
  var mydata = this.http.get()...

 this.signForm = new FormGroup({
  'Name': new FormControl(mydata.name),
  'Age': new FormControl(mydata.age)   
 });

  this.signForm.submit() //Wished this method existed
}
```

I want my browser to redirect to the page I am submitting the form to.

EDIT: Sorry..! My concerns was mostly how to submit this form. Not to get the data and populate the form. My code was just a template.. It is the this.signForm.submit() method I am missing

Comment: You want to send the form back to server?

Comment: I want to sent to a different server

Answer (score 5):

The mistake you are doing here is that you can't access data in `mydata` without subscribing to it because `http.get()` returns `Observable`

**You can use subscribe**

```
submitMyform() {
  //first i call an API and get some data
  var mydata = this.http.get()...
 mydata.subscribe((data) =>{
   this.signForm = new FormGroup({
    'Name': new FormControl(mydata.name),
    'Age': new FormControl(mydata.age)   
   });
   this.http.post('url', this.signForm);
 });
}
```

**Or async/await**

```
async submitMyform() {
  //first i call an API and get some data
  var mydata = await this.http.get().toPromise();
  this.signForm = new FormGroup({
    'Name': new FormControl(mydata.name),
    'Age': new FormControl(mydata.age)   
  });
 this.http.post('url', this.signForm);
}
```

### Update:

I have tried several things to send post request with redirect in Angular. But the only one which worked for me was creating hidden `<form>`

For this I have created this method

```
submitForm(action, method, formGroup: FormGroup) {
    const form = document.createElement('form');
    form.style.display = 'none';
    form.method = method;
    form.action = action;
    let input;
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(formGroup.value)) {
      input = document.createElement('input');
      input.name = key;
      input.id = key;
      input.value = value;
      form.appendChild(input);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
      form.submit();
  }
```

The best way here would be to submit it without the `appendChild()` but then it would produce this error

> Submit was canceled because form is no connected.

Comment: this.http.post()... It doesnt redirect the browser does it ?

Comment: @Jepzen No it doesn't

Comment: But it also returns data like `.get()`

Comment: I need to redirect the browser.

Comment: To another webpage? Not a route in Angular router, right?

Comment: Another web page yes

Comment: I hope there was a submit method ofn the FormGroup object i could trigger

Comment: @Jepzen I have updated the answer. There is probably some better solution but this worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have conditions on your form (like required fields, or restricted fields), you can use the form builder like so.

```
constructor(
  fb: FormBuilder,
  http: HttpClient
) {
  http.get(...).subscribe(response => fb.group(response));
}
```

Tha should build the form from a direct JSON object. The issue is that you have to know your form model in advance to avoid getting errors. And reactive forms aren't made for that.

Instead, you should rely on template driven forms. [The official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#key-differences) can tell you more.

You can use `Object.keys` to iterate over the keys.

```js
rawResponse$ = this.http.get(...).pipe(share());
keys$ = this.rawResponse$.pipe(response => Object.keys(response));
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let key of keys$ | async">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="(rawResponse$ | async)?[key]">
</ng-container>
```

Or something similar.